# PySpark unable to find python location while running locally

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to build out unit tests for a pyspark package and therefore need to run the tests locally. Some tests work fine but others are giving me a strange error where the JVM is unable to locate "python". I have a simple example below along with a portion of the stack trace.

I am running pyspark through anaconda, Python 3.5, Spark 2.4.0, and on a Debian Windows linux subsystem. I have also tried setting `SPARK_HOME`, `PYTHONPATH` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON` environmental variables to every option I could think of. Any ideas?

**Example**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').appName('testAPP').getOrCreate()

df_test = pd.DataFrame({
'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
'C': [1.23, 4.56, 7.89, 1.01, 11.2, 13.4],
'D': [True, True, False, False, True, False]
})

df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_test)

print(df_spark.count())
```

**Stacktrace Section**

```
File "/tmp/nht_core_project/spark_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(df_spark.count())
  File "/home/ross/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 455, in count
    return int(self._jdf.count())
  File "/home/ross/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/ross/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/ross/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o44.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
```

Comment: Please check if your pandas dtypes have any `object` types. If yes, convert them to a solid type like `string`, `int`, `boolean`, etc

Comment: thanks for the input, only column 'B' was `object` type and with this removed/converted the issue still remains